# How to use webui-popover with hover and ajax content

Tags: ajax, hover, popover

I try to use popover https://github.com/sandywalker/webui-popover. I need the 'quora' popover functionality: link should be clickable but hover should show popover with ajax loaded content.

---

I tried the following:

```
  $(function(){
    function details_in_popup(link, div_id){
      $.ajax({
          url: link,
          success: function(response){
              $('#'+div_id).html(response);
          }
      });
      return '<div id="'+ div_id +'">Loading...</div>';
    }

    $('a.user_popover').livequery(function(){
      var link = 'your_url_there';
      $(this).webuiPopover({
        content: function(data){
          var div_id =  "tmp-id-" + $.now();
          return details_in_popup(link, div_id);
        },
        placement: 'bottom',
        trigger: 'hover',
        cache: false
      });
    })
  })
```

Comment: Where exactly do you have troubles?

Comment: It is not possible to use 'hover' event with ajax loaded content. If I use 'async' type with 'url', the popover is triggered only by click.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the url for your ajax request by data attributes `data-url` or by `url` parameter when initialize webui, then set the `trigger` parameter with hover.

something like this

```
(function($){
    $('a.user_popover').webuiPopover({
        title:'Sample',
        placement: 'bottom',
        trigger:'hover',
        type:'async',//content type, values:'html','iframe','async'
        url: 'your_url_there'
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know it very old question, but I am answering as I guess it can help others.

Following is working for me. I use **bootstrap 3** and webuipopover plugin  - **v1.2.5**

#### HTML:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign popup-ajax"></span>
```

#### Javascript:

```
$('.popup-ajax').webuiPopover({
    title: "Info",
    placement: 'top',
    height: 210,
    width: 400,
    animation: 'fade',
    html: true,
    type:'async',
    content: function(){
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'use_your_url_here',
            success: function(res){
                var html = '<p>'+res+'</p>';
                $("#"+target+" .webui-popover-content").html(html);
            },
            error: function(res){
                var error = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                html = ['<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'];
                html.push('Error:'+ error.error+'</div>');
                $("#"+target+" .webui-popover-content").html(html.join(' '));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hope that can help.